# Is there any way to sync container in swift object storage with bucket in IBM COS S3?

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure, object-storage

Example:

Swift object storage

```
authurl=
username=
apikey=
conatainer = test1
```

IBM COS

```
access_key=
secret_key=
bucket_name= test2
```

could we sync container and the bucket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to sync containers by using the API at this time.  Container sync for ICOS is on the roadmap but not yet slated for a scheduled release.

Note that sync for replication and data resiliency is not necessary with the Cross Region object storage. Objects are sliced, encrypted, and dispersed across data centers in Washington DC, Dallas, and San Jose, and it would take catastrophic failures at two of these locations simultaneously for data to be at risk.

Sync for reasons of minimizing latency can be valuable.  Currently, Cross Region object storage is only available in the US, but similar offerings are in the works for Europe and Asia-Pacific.

Answer (score 0):

AS Nick Lange pointed out, Using API to syn containers and bucket is not possible yet.

However, If you want to sync the existing container with COS S3, you can use open source tool like [Rclone](https://rclone.org/) . Rclone is powerfull because unless S3cmd, it uses multipart upload, you can log, you can add several cloud target and sync/move/push/retrieve/filter/dry-run etc data ( like you can do with rsync for files ).

Now if you want a Graphical tool that is free and that is doing the same, you have [Cloudberry S3 explorer](https://www.cloudberrylab.com/explorer/amazon-s3.aspx) . This tool has native Swift support and S3 Compatible support . Then you just have to drag and drop all your data.

Hope this help.